# How to insert value in tkinter entry widget while entry is disabled

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Am trying to insert value in `tkinter entry` while the `widget` is disabled.I want to achieve that for the value in the `entry widget` not to be deleted.Have checked this site to find similar question to address this but couldn't found any.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


blow = [("january", "2013")]


def func():
    for child in tree.get_children():
        sum =(tree.item(child, "values")[1])
        e1.delete(0, tk.END)
        e1.insert(0, sum)
        print(sum)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")

tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=("columns1", "columns"), show="headings",
selectmode="browse")
tree.heading("#1", text="Month")
tree.heading("#2", text="Year")

for n in blow:
    tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(n))
tree.pack()

b1 = tk.Button(text="insert", command=func)
b1.pack()

e1 = tk.Entry()
e1.config(state="disable")
e1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: enable it, insert the value, disable it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way to do this need to enable  the `entry` by using `config` after that then i `disable` it

```
def func():
    for child in tree.get_children():
        sum = (tree.item(child, "values")[1])
        e1.config(state="normal")
        e1.delete(0, tk.END)
        e1.insert(0, sum)
        print(sum)
        e1.config(state="disable")
```